# Web Audio: Normalization filter?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, signal-processing, web-audio-api

*How do I normalize a signal in web audio?*

I guess, this can be done with a [`ConvolverNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ConvolverNode). That node has an option [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ConvolverNode/normalize). However I don't know what values should go into the buffer in order not to distort the incoming signal other than normalizing it. IOW: I wonder what is the neutral convolution function.

Background: I am trying to normalize white noise that I piped through a bandpass filter ([`BiquadFilterNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode)). At low frequencies, the amplitude of the output from the filter is very small. Of course, I could put a gain node behind with a gain value that depends on the frequency. However, if normalization is straight forward, that seems to be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no builtin normalization method.  The ConvolverNode's normalization does something very different from what you want.

Comment: *What do you think about building a normalization method using an analyzer node connected to a gain node?* (the analyzer node would look for max. amplitude, and the gain node would be adjusted accordingly)

Comment: That would work.  But if you're going to do that, might as well use a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` to find the max and apply the gain itself to the data.

Comment: AudioWorklets are still not compatible with Firefox however